# Find all the values of a,b,c s.t that x divides $a^2-cb,c^2-ab,b^2-ac$ where x is an integer

Tags: divisibility, integers

if
$$x = \frac{a^2-cb}{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)},\\ y =  \frac{c^2-ab}{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)},\\ z = \frac{b^2-ac}{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)}.$$ And a,b,c are integers,  do you know of any way i can pick a,b,c s.t x,y and z are integers (i am not looking for a specific example but rather all the values of a,b,c s.t x,y and z are integers)? Nothing i try seems to work so i would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "*Nothing i try seems to work*" $\;-\;$ What *have* you tried?

Comment: @dxiv i tried adding $a^2-cb$ to $c^2-ab$ then dividing by (++)(2+2+2−−−) in the hopes that something might cancel and the problem would become easier. but that didn't work.

Comment: $$x+y+z=\frac1{a+b+c},$$ so that narrows it down a bit

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ooh, i didn't see that. thank you so much. i will get started on that.

Comment: Should the numerator for $z$ be $b^2-ac,$ or is it really not symmetric? My previous observation assumed $b^2-ac.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews no, unfortunately it's not. its not symmetric

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ooh, againn, sorry. you are right. what i meant to write was $b^2-ac$

Comment: Based on Thomas's observation it seems that you can not have a solution with ALL 6 values integers - if a+b+c is an integer then the sum of x+y+z is a fraction. I would conclude that there are no such values as you desire.

Comment: @Moti what if $a+b+c = \pm 1$

Comment: So now we have two additional conditions for the sums.:) 4 possible relations

Comment: Try (a, b, c) - (1, -1,1)